# Is there any way I can shorten properties with similar statements but different returns?

Tags: python, class-properties

```
class....

    @property
    def degrees(self):
        hem, degs, mins, secs = self._correction()
        return degs

    @property
    def minutes(self):
        hem, degs, mins, secs = self._correction()
        return mins

    @property
    def seconds(self):
        hem, degs, mins, secs = self._correction()
        return secs
```

I was thinking that *def* could be truncated like:

```
@property
def hemisphere, degrees, minutes, seconds(self):
    hem, degs, mins, secs = self._correction()
    return hem, degs, mins, secs
```

so that when I call 'hemisphere' it will *return* hem values and so on.

PS.
I know that my *return* statement in the latter was wrong. I hope you get my point.

Comment: You could do `return self._correction()[0]` but that is about all

Comment: This seems a much simpler and more obvious solution than any of the answers.

Comment: do you really need `@property` ? It would be simpler to do `self.hem, self.degs, self.mins, self.secs = self._correction()` in `__init__`

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @xjcl commented, and on the basis of simplicity in preference to seemingly unecessary complication/obfuscation:

```
class....

    @property
    def degrees(self):
        return self._correction()[1]

    @property
    def minutes(self):
        return self._correction()[2]

    @property
    def seconds(self):
        return self._correction()[3]
```

Comment: this is actually the answer i need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could override `__getattr__` method

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    values = ["hemisphere", "degrees", "minutes", "seconds"]
    if item in values:
        return self._correction()[values.index(item)]
    raise AttributeError(f"'{self.__class__.__name__}' object has no attribute '{item}'")
```

Comment: This seems like a complicated and totally non-obvious way of trying to address the question.

Comment: @barny Feel free to provide an answer so ;)

Comment: @xjcl already did in their comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ways you could shorten this, I would write another helper function:

```
from functools import wraps

def unpack(rng, fn, propertize=False):
    for i in rng:
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, __i=i, **kwargs):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)[i]
        yield property(wrapper) if propertize else wrapper
```

...

```
class Something:
    hemisphere, degrees, minutes, seconds = unpack(
        range(4), Something._correction, propertize=True
    )
```

Comment: This also seems like a complicated and totally non-obvious way of trying to address the question.